# goroutines taking way too long

Tags: go

My understanding is that for an unbuffered channel (`jobs`) you need both a sender and receiver which I have but something about the order of my code is wrong, it is taking a very long time to complete.
What am I missing here?

```
const numWorkers = 5
type workerJob struct {
    FirstID   string
    SecondID string
}

func worker(ctx *gin.Context, fs *firestore.Client, jobs <-chan *workerJob, done chan<- bool) {
    for job := range jobs {
        firstID := job.FirstID
        secondID := job.SecondID
        if err := saveUpdate(ctx, firstID, secondID, fs); err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    done <- true
}

func UpdateSomething(ctx *gin.Context) {
    fs, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "some_ID")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer fs.Close()

    docsnaps, err := fs.CollectionGroup("someCollection").Where("someCondition", "==", true).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    uniqueSomethings := make(map[string]struct{})
    jobs := make(chan *workerJob)
    done := make(chan bool, numWorkers)
    for w := 1; w <= numWorkers; w++ {
         go worker(ctx, fs, jobs, done)
    }
    for _, docsnap := range docsnaps {
        var someType SomeType
        err := docsnap.DataTo(&someType)
        if err != nil { 
            // handle error
        }
        for _, prop := range someType.prop {
            if strings.Contains(prop.Name, "someString") {
                someID := prop.Name[strings.LastIndex(prop.Name, ":")+1:]
                if _, ok := uniqueSomethings[someID]; !ok {
                    uniqueSomethings[someID] = struct{}{}
                    job := &workerJob{
                        FirstID: dashboard.CustomerID,
                        SecondID:   someID[strings.Index(someID, "_")+1:],
                    }
                    jobs <- job
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(jobs)
    for i := 1; i <= numWorkers; i++ {
        select {
        case <-done:
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Note that a "goroutine" is a single word ;-)

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with your code. Since both the jobs and results channels are unbuffered, it's easy to reason about: `numWorkers` goroutines are concurrently reading form the `jobs` channel, so if you have ≤ `numWorkers` jobs, they will be acquired almost instantly. _Then_ things become more interesting as all the worker goroutines are writing the results of their processing into a single unbuffered channel, so they all will wait until the `for` loop which drains the `done` channel. Now note that until a worker goroutine manages to write its result to the `done` channel it cannot…

Comment: …get a new job to perform, if is the number of jobs is way higher than the number of workers, some workers might just sit there waiting until their result is accepted. Well, so on the second thought there _is_ a problem with your code: a worker is coded in a way to process any number of jobs it manages to acquire, but you only wait for `numWorker` results back, which is incorrect: you need to count the number of jobs submitted and wait for that many resuts back.

Comment: Now consider that whatever `saveUpdate` does, is supposedly not instantaneous, and several concurrent calls to `saveUpdate` may even be naturally serialized on that "fire store" thing (whatever it means, sounds like a DB engine). In this case, no amount of parallelism is going to make the whole thing complete faster.

Comment: @kostix the `numWorker` (5) is by design, I only want up to 5 workers working concurrently. Although what you wrote is helpful.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend replacing the `done` channel with a `WaitGroup`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand why, but I have been able to bring down the time by a factor of 6! I decided to create a slice of jobs and then create a channel with a predefined capacity - the lenght of that slice, then loop over the slice and send the jobs to the channel here's how it looks:

```
func UpdateSomething(ctx *gin.Context) {
    fs, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "some_ID")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer fs.Close()

    docsnaps, err := fs.CollectionGroup("someCollection").Where("someCondition", "==", true).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    uniqueSomethings := make(map[string]struct{})
    jobsArr := make([]*workerJob, 0)
   
    for _, docsnap := range docsnaps {
        var someType SomeType
        err := docsnap.DataTo(&someType)
        if err != nil { 
            // handle error
        }
        for _, prop := range someType.prop {
            if strings.Contains(prop.Name, "someString") {
                someID := prop.Name[strings.LastIndex(prop.Name, ":")+1:]
                if _, ok := uniqueSomethings[someID]; !ok {
                    uniqueSomethings[someID] = struct{}{}
                    job := &workerJob{
                        FirstID: dashboard.CustomerID,
                        SecondID:   someID[strings.Index(someID, "_")+1:],
                    }
                    jobsArr = append(jobsArr, job)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    done := make(chan bool, numWorkers)
    jobs := make(chan *workerJob, len(jobsArr))
     
    for w := 1; w <= numWorkers; w++ {
         go worker(ctx, fs, jobs, done)
    }
    for _, job := range jobsArr {
        jobs <- job
    }
    close(jobs)
    for i := 1; i <= numWorkers; i++ {
        select {
        case <-done:
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: This happens because your original job pusher pushes only 1 JOB to pool of Workers a time; Now lets consider your worker can work fast and does the job in same amount of time it takes for you to push 2 jobs so this means when you push the third job your first worker is done and waiting for new assignment and rest of the workers will stay idle.

Comment: This above assumption will mean you will never be able to get efficiency for your pool size; Now when you use buffered channel your workers can start working faster and start together when so many jobs are pushed together. Does this make sense?

Comment: Also instead of done channel you should use wait group and before adding job to queue add it so you will not require this hacky way of waiting for jobs to be done by receiving n inputs in channel